# Why does Response.Write("<someting>") not work in ASP.NET code-behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have this code in my ASP.NET code-behind file:

```
Response.Write("<someting>")
```

But it doesn't work. If I remove the `<` tag delimiter, then it writes the content to the page.

My question is: how can I write an XML string to the page from a code-behind?

Comment: i want to prepare an .aspx page for answer a xmlhttprequest in code behined. it easy for me that answer be in xml format but first i must get data from sql DB. is it possible ?!

Comment: of course it's possible, but that's another question entirely.  please only ask one question at a time. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is already fine.  Your `<someting>` tag isn't showing on the page because the browser is expecting HTML, so it interprets `<someting>` as an HTML tag it doesn't understand and displays nothing.  If you look at the source of the page you should see the tag.

Your XMLHttpRequest (XHR) request should be able to read this data as XML without a problem, even though it's not displayed directly in the browser.  However, as outlined in another answer, you should ideally change the content-type to `text/xml`, so the client knows what data format to expect.

Comment: ok, is it possible to change content-type more than one time in one page ? how to set that to defualt ?

Comment: @biglibigli A page can only have one content-type because it's returned as a single HTTP response header.  You could set a default content-type in a base class from which you inherit all your pages (or HTTP handlers, whichever you're using).

Answer (score 4):

You need to HTML encode it:

```
Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<someting>"));
```

But if you are writing an XML you should use a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) or [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to build it first to ensure that it is valid and only then write it to the response.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the encoding (though tags shouldn't be encoded, just the text in between), and also for mentioning that's it's best not done manually, but instead use XmlDocument (or similar), which knows all the ins and outs needed to do this correctly

Answer (score 2):

If you are outputting XML, you should first set the Content Type as follows:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Also, it would probably be better to use a Handler (.ashx), not a page (.aspx), as it cuts out all sorts of extra page/form processing you don't need.

Then feel free to generate your page with Response.Write, eg:

```
Response.Write("<something>foobar</something>");
```

Since it's XML, you will need to view the generated output with an XML viewer.  Internet Explorer will display well-formed XML as a tree-structure if you ensure the content type is correct.

You should also ensure XML content starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Comment: very good will, i want to prepare an .aspx page for answer a xmlhttprequest in code behined. it easy for me that answer be in xml format but first i must get data from sql DB. is it possible ?!

Comment: and will how can write normally again after i use : Response.ContentType = "text/xml";